# Hidrogen generator - electric problem

Tags: electric-machine

I made an Hidrogen generator (HHO) like YouTube :
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zq8YMON9hjA&list=PLPCtNZjqSVUhWVzuxEkzlyrz1CatH8OiF&index=29&t=504s
but , it does not working at all. 
Electric issues- I Do not know why.
Especially , in the project it îs not mention the electric resistance.
I put the component into a PC frame.
I made an electrolite with KOH 15-20% of water of about 2kohms. I used a PC 12V source 20 A. And nothing happened inside of Orange collor- photo- Hydrogen generator- see Photos- no Bubling, no Hydrogen.
I made exactly , except electrolite- it îs not specified the concentration or resistance, please help me with some ideas.The man who made the project does not answer to my question at comments of video clip.
Many thanks.
Costas.[image: Hydrogen generator (HHO)]

Comment: Sorry, but not many of us are going to watch a video for you. Put the essential details, a diagram and details of the electrode material into your question. Spelling in English is "hydrogen" and chemical elements do not get capital letters.

Comment: With 12V and water with any amount of electrolyte, you should get bubbles.  Is your power supply really putting out 12V?  Many PC power supplies need a minimum load, and can be otherwise tricky to keep turned on.  Connect the wires to your hydrolysis container, turn on the power, and check the voltage.   This is a simple thing that we did as kids using a 12V battery charger and water with a little table salt.  It should be **very** easy to do if the power supply is working.

Comment: Bubble, bubble, bubble.  Light a match. Pop-squeak.  Hydrogen makes a really funny noise when it explodes.

Comment: @JRE given the OP has no clue and may have more hydrogen than they expect - it may make **much** more of a bang ....

Comment: Your volt meter is only showing 6 volts, unless I am reading it incorrectly.  As @JRE suggests, maybe the power supply is not active.

Comment: @SolarMike:  The hydrogen/oxygen mixture is generated in the cup with the orange lid.  Not much volume, and it won't put it under pressure so you really can't build up any large amounts of gas.

Comment: @JRE as one who has seen car batteries explode and the air space in a battery is small compared to the total volume - I can promise you **I** won't be testing your **theory**...

Comment: No theory.  I've **done** that very thing.  Hell, I've set off a liter soda bottle of hydrogen/oxygen mix.   It was loud, but it didn't even shatter the bottle.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture you have shown, nothing is connected to one of the terminals on the container.  I assume it is meant to be the yellow wires.

If you are using a PC power supply, then a few possible problems spring to mind:

- The power supply may not actually be switching on.  Modern PC power supplies need more than just power going in.  They will sit in standby mode until something tells them to turn on.
- The load on the power supply is too low for the voltage regulation to work, and it will not turn on.
- The load on the power supply is too great, and it has shut down to protect itself.

If nothing else, you need to check the voltage across your cell to see if there is any voltage.

Comment: Yes endeed , the power supply working so tricky. I Will check again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't watch the video, but I suggest that you review the materials that you are using for the electrodes, particularly the anode. Some materials will passivate and limit the current. For a KOH electrolyte solution I would recommend using nickel as an anode.

Comment: I used stainless steel plates for anode and catode.

Comment: Prepare fresh electrodes by sanding/polishing the surface and insert an ammeter in your circuit. Monitor the current after quickly introducing the electrodes to the electrolyte. If you get an initial current reading that decays with time, you are probably passivating the surface of the anode.

Comment: @Costas: That information belongs in the question, not buried in the comments, as requested below your original post. Make it easy for us to help you. Read all the comments carefully and edit your question and try to supply the missing information. If you don't bother then why should we?

Comment: I need time to obtain some measurement devices. Thank You for opinion.